# How do I prevent the cursor from going to a monitor that is turned off?

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, laptop

I have a laptop which I connect to an external screen through HDMI, under Kubuntu 15.04. I have this external screen set to be the main screen, and the laptop screen set to turn off when I close the lid.

After I close the laptop lid, the screen turns off (I'm pretty sure it does because if I open it just a little, there is no light), and the image remains on my main display. The problem is that if I move my cursor to the right, it moves completely off screen, as if it were on the turned off monitor. If I move it a lot to the right, then to the left, it takes a while before it shows up on my main screen, confirming that it is indeed disappearing on the off screen.

The turned off laptop screen shows up under display settings.

How can I make the cursor unable to move to the screen that is turned off?

Ideally, I'd like a setting that enables this only when my external monitor is the only one that is on. If both the external monitor and the laptop monitors are on, I should automatically be allowed to use both.

Comment: In the settings there is actually an option switch "Built-in display " and you should be able to set it on/off, so that your connected display is treated as the main one

Comment: @Serg can you detail where that is please? I did set my external display as the main one, but my cursor can still go off screen.

Comment: Just disable one of the monitors while you're not working on it. It's not just the mouse that's the issue; new windows might be created on that screen and you wouldn't see them.

Comment: @o9000 that's not really a solution, though. If that's the only way, how can I disable the laptop's built in monitor? It's already turned off, and I can't unplug that one.

Comment: You can try writing a shell script to do it using the events as described in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaptopLidAndDockScripts and the command line program xrandr to turn on/off the laptop monitor (usually called LVDS1). But it's a bit tricky to get it right; if it fails you might end up with both monitors turned off. It's safer to do it by hand.

Comment: I also suggest *duplicating* the image to both displays, even if they have different resolutions. Since you are normally working with one closed, it should not be an issue for you.

Comment: I use two commands for this in my workflow: `xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto` turns on the HDMI output and duplicates on it the laptop's output (if the monitor has a larger resolution than the laptop display, the monitor will use the native resolution and the laptop display will show a truncated image). You can also add `--same-as LVDS1` in case your monitor is already configured in a different way. To turn off the external monitor: `xrandr --output HDMI1 --off`. It's simple enough that there is no point in scripting this; it takes just a few seconds to run this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You may Try **CMD + P** key to **disable another monitor**.

  **OR**
- Open **Display Configuration in System Settings** and look at following **Screenshot**.

[image: KDE - Display Configuration - System Settings]

Comment: It doesn't look like that in Kubuntu...

Comment: But that will cause my external to have the same resolution as the laptop monitor, which is much smaller.

Comment: 15.04. I can't test on an actual PC ATM. In a VM, windows key + p doesn't do anything. I'm not sure what you mean by start+p.

Comment: @IVlad I Have Updated the answer. Is it appropriate?

Comment: Yes, that is how it looks like right now. I honestly can't remember if I tried to disable it like that and whether or not I could still move the cursor to it, and I can't try for a couple of days. Regardless, it doesn't look like this will get much more attention, so I'm going to accept your answer and award you the bounty (no point letting it vanish) and let you know when I get to try it on an actual installation.

Comment: @IVlad Are you running it inside VirtualBox on Windows?

Comment: Yes, I am right now. I don't have an actual install on the laptop I'm on right now, and I'm not home (no installation media or live USB with me unfortunately). But it looks like that, both from what I can remember and what shows up in virtualbox.

Comment: I tested it and disabling does indeed work. Do you know if there is a way to make it disabled when the lid is closed and then automatically enable it when it's open?

Comment: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=88659